# How to use typeid to to figure its type for the data in a pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a push item function for a stack class. I wanted to check if *data had empty values, and if there is return an exception. The problem is I made the stack class for strings and later changed it so generic types can be used. Now *data->data() dont work for anyother types other than strings. So i wanted to check each *data type. So I added an If statement to check if the pointer Id looks like string.

So by doing this, I hoped that if(*data->data() will only execute for strings. But the problem is it checks for integers as well. I keep getting this error : error: member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union.
How can fix this issue?

```
      void push(Node<T> **head,T *data){


    string s = typeid(*data).name();
    if(s=="NSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE"){
        if(*data->data() == NULL){
            throw NoDataException();
        }
    }
    else{
        if(s=="i"){
            cout<<"here"<<endl;
        }
    }

    Node<T> *temp = new Node<T>;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = *head;
    *head = temp;
};
```

Comment: `std::string::data()` is never NULL. Empty strings are fully legitimate citizens. Your check is unwarranted. Just drop it altogether.

Comment: Besides, `NSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE` will not work with any other compiler, and can stop working tomorrow for your compiler. There is absolutely no guarantee that `type_info::name()` returns any particular string.

Comment: I don't see a string being compared to null there, since `T` is missing. Still, the example remains very unclear.

Comment: @n.m. okay thanks for that. I will drop it. But do you know why it still checks even if the string s is different?

Comment: First, extract a minimal example, @user2775042. Then, if you didn't find the issue yourself, post a question here. Do not switch this order!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use helper functions to do the check.

Add the following functions.

```
// A generic function for all types.
template <typename T> bool isEmpty(T const& t) { return false; }

// An overload for std::string.
bool isEmpty(std::string const& s) { return s.empty(); }
```

And then, replace:

```
string s = typeid(*data).name();
if(s=="NSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE") {
    if(*data->data() == NULL){
        throw NoDataException();
    }
}
else{
    if(s=="i"){
        cout<<"here"<<endl;
    }
}
```

by

```
if ( isEmpty(*data) ) {
   throw NoDataException();
} else {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: `s.data() == NULL` will never be `true` for any valid string reference: for an empty string it's required to return a pointer to a NUL character.  The question had `*data->data() == NULL` which works, but confusingly compares a `char` to `NULL`.  Perhaps `data->empty()`

Comment: @user2775042: yes... it will work because `NULL` is defined to be `0`, and so you get a comparison between a `char` and `0` which is legal and functional.  Still, `NULL` is meant to denote a NULL pointer, and comparison of a `char` with a pointer is illegal: if you switched to C++11's `nullptr` the compiler would alert you.  You could reasonably say `*data->data() == '\0'` which is a comparison with the ASCII NUL character, but simply using `.empty()` is the usual way to do this.

Comment: Just curiosity: why didn't you fully specialize *isEmpty*?

Comment: @skypjack: see [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)